# How to build a regex for a number of parameters in a textbox with commas?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regular expression for multiple entries in a textbox with commas.
Examples: a textbox accepting values with commas like:

**c++,java,php,python,c,asp.net**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Regex for that.

```
var str = "c++,java,php,python,c,asp.net";
var res = str.split(",");
```

The result of res will be an array with the values:

```
"c++", "java", "php", "python", "c", "asp.net"
```

A regex that has a match for each part would be:

```
/([^,]+)/g
```